# Trying to load HTML into a div with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I've spent enough hours googling this to feel comfortable posting this- even though i'm sure it's a simple solution. I'm just getting into a webdev so pardon my ignorance. As the title says i'm simply trying to have the content of an HTML file appear in a div after a button is pressed. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<button id="button" class="linkGeneration">Press me</button>

<div id="renderArea" class="contentArea">
    <!-- CONTENT SHOULD GENERATE HERE -->
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#renderArea").load($(this).attr('../html/content.html'));
    });
});
```

I'm not getting any errors, the button simply does nothing. I do have Jquery properly applied in my HTML as well.

Any suggestions on how to fix this OR a different method that might be simpler? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The button doesn't have an attribute named `../html/content.html`, so `$(this).attr('../html/content.html')` is not returning anything.

If you want to load from the URL, just use that as the argument to `.load()`, you don't need `.attr()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#renderArea").load('../html/content.html');
    });
});
```